# I'm having trouble adding a hyperlink to my ordered list item

Tags: html, css

I looked at examples and tried adding single and double quotations and parentheses but it took away the words on my site and only put those symbols and added the link to the rest of the code instead of the specified list item. I added my index.html and stared the line I'm having trouble with to this message but it won't allow me to add pictures yet because this is my first question apparently.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>LIVing Vintage</title>
        <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="itemdetail1.html" rel="itemdetail1 page" type="html">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href=".index.html"> Home </a>
        </nav>
        <header class="top-header"> 
            <h1>LIVing Vintage</h1> 
        
        </header> 
        <div class="main">
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vintage_(design)"target="_blank"> 
                More information about vintage design</a>
        </div>


            <h2> Welcome to your new favorite vintage collectables page!

            </h2>
            <br>

        <h3 >[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m11Jj.png)
            I'm Olivia but I usually go by Liv, and I love going to antique/ thrift stores and yard sales looking 
            for cool and unique items to go with the many collections I have available to my favorite people, my <strong>customers</strong>!
        </h3>

<div id="border_div"> 
    
        <p1 style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: 25px;">
            Introducing the eclectic treasure trove of vintage items that I've painstakingly curated over the years, each piece now holds a 
            special place in my heart as I embark on the journey to finance my college education. 
            This diverse collection, gathered from antique shops, estate sales, and even hidden gems found in 
            forgotten attics, reflects not only the rich history but also my dedication to achieving my academic dreams.
        </p1>
        <br>

        <p2 style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: 25px;">
            Among the gems of this collection is an ornate, 19th-century grandfather clock made of mahogany that has stood the test of time. 
            Then there's the exquisite set of hand-painted porcelain teacups, a testament to the craftsmanship of a bygone era. 
            Vintage typewriters, with their intricate mechanical workings, offer a glimpse into the past, inviting collectors 
            and history enthusiasts alike to experience the nostalgia of a simpler time. With this collection, I hope 
            to share not just objects of beauty and historical significance but also my unwavering determination to invest 
            in my future through the sale of these cherished antiques. Each piece has a story to tell, and I am eager
             to pass them on to individuals who will appreciate their history and help me achieve my educational aspirations.
             </p2>
             </div>
        
        <ol style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: 25px;">
        Here are a few of the available items I still have in my collections:
        *<li> <a href="itemdetail1.html" 19th-century Grandfather Clock </a> *
        </li> 
        <li>Hand-painted Porcelain Teacups</li>
        <li>Vintage Typewriters</li>
        <li>Art Deco Table Lamps</li>
        <li>Vintage Leather-bound Books</li>
        <li> Antique Pocket Watches</li>
    </ol>     
             <ul style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: 25px;">I believe my collection to be <em>special </em>because it displays<strong>
                <li>historical significance</li>
                <li>exceptional </li>
                <li>craftsmanship</li>
                <li>uncommon finds</li>
                <li>nostalgia and sentimental value</li>
                <li>potential investment</li>
            </strong></ul> 
        

        
    <p3 style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: 25px;">
        Thank you to everyone, for supporting my journey and appreciating the beauty and history within each piece
        of my cherished antique collection. Your patronage not only enriches your lives but also brings me one step 
        closer to achieving my dreams through education. Your support means the world to me.
    </p3>
        
    </body>
    

</html>
```

I tried looking at other examples those but it took away the words on my site and added the link to the rest of the code instead of the specified list item.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the closing tag of the href attribute – you need to add a closing angle bracket, like this:

```
<a href="itemdetail1.html"> 19th-century Grandfather Clock </a>
```